# Unable to install app build to iOS 9 created using jenkins. Error says Symlink has absolute path

Tags: jenkins, symlink, ios9, ios-9-beta5

I am creating an application. I created an adhoc build to test the app in my iPad. I have used proper code signing certificate and provisioning profile in the build. I have 2 iPads, 1 has iOS 8.3 and another has iOS9.5 beta.

When I tries to install the application in both iPads, iPad with iOS8.3 allows the app to be installed but in iOS 9.5 beta it fails.

I am using Xcode > Window > Devices and choose my iPad and drag-drop the build in installed application. It gives an error like: "App installation failed - Could not write to the device."

EDIT: the console has following error log:

1. Invalid symlink:
2. Stream extractor got error: Error Domain=SZExtractorErrorDomain Code=2 "Invalid symlink:
3. __dispatch_source_read_socket_block_invoke_2:188: Failed to finish extraction: Error Domain=SZExtractorErrorDomain Code=3 "This extractor previously encountered an error and can no longer be used." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=This extractor previously encountered an error and can no longer be used.}

Please help me with this.

Comment: Worked a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We had the same issue today and found a solution that seems to work.

If you're building with jenkins using the xcodebuild plugin, make sure you unselect the "Generate Archive" option in the general build settings
[image]

This solved the install problem on iOS9 for us

Comment: What if you need to generate an archive though?

Answer (score 2):

I am also seeing this issue. Looking at the console log when the app is being installed I see an error something like this:

`[MIFileManager realPathForURL:ifChildOfURL:]: Rejecting /var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.BGmQCm/extracted/Payload/<app_name>.app/Frameworks/<framework_name>.framework/<framework_name>.framework -> /Users/mobile/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<app_name>-bgvxkqkwligkcjcwrtdolronntfp/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/<app_name_dir>/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/<framework_name>.framework, as absolute symlinks are not allowed`

This happens when I actually archive using xcodebuild (Xcode 7.1). If I by-pass archiving and use the `PackageApplication` tool, the install works fine, which I presume what the Jenkin's plugin is doing.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Eric Genet's answer in that the issue seems to be that the xcodebuild plugin can no longer generate an ipa and archive successfully from the same plugin.

What I did to workaround the problem while still maintaining the archive was by separating the generating of the archive and the ipa into 2 different xcodebuild steps. The two build steps had the same settings except for one had "Generate Archive" checked, and the other had "Pack application and build ipa". By splitting them up this made it so that both the ipa and archive succeeded in being built.